# Get execution results of child process C++

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I've been trying to implement an online judge, but I'm stuck..
I use fork to create a child process and then from the child process I use the system command to start the program I'm supposed to test.

This is the program I use to test the grader. It's in an infinite loop, but I just comment that line to make it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int a, b;
    scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b);
    while (1);
    printf ("%d\n", a + b);

    return 0;
}
```

And the grader I coded so far is

```
struct timeval start, end;
    struct rlimit rl, default_memory, default_time;
    getrlimit (RLIMIT_AS, &default_memory);
    getrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &default_time);

    pid_t pid = fork ();

    gettimeofday (&start, NULL);

    if (pid < 0) printf ("Error\n");
    else if (pid == 0) { // child process
        if (memory_limit > 0) {
            rl.rlim_cur = rl.rlim_max = memory_limit;
            setrlimit (RLIMIT_AS, &rl);
        }

        if (time_limit > 0) {
            rl.rlim_cur = rl.rlim_max = time_limit / 1000 + 1;
            setrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &rl);
        }


        ptrace (PTRACE_TRACEME, pid, NULL, NULL);
        system ("./sum < in.txt > out.txt");

        setrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &default_time);
        setrlimit (RLIMIT_AS, &default_memory);
    }
    else { // parent process
        int *status;


            // Is this ok?
            // Because here http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace it says that
            // PTRACE_GETSIGINFO is used to get information about the signal that
            // caused the stop. And I'm interested If the program was killed because of
            // rlimit (exceeding time or memory limit) or if it was something else.
        ptrace (PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, NULL, NULL);
        if (wait (status) == -1) return 1; // waiting for the child process to finish

        if (WIFSIGNALED (status)) {
            int exit_signal = WTERMSIG (status);
            printf ("Terminated with signal: %d.\n", exit_signal);
            switch (exit_signal) {
                case 0:
                    printf ("OK\n");
                    break;
                case SIGSEGV: // RLIMIT_AS -- SIGSEGV is sent, when the memory limit is exceeded
                    printf ("Memory Limit Exceeded\n");
                    break;
                case SIGXCPU: // RLIMIT_CPU -- when soft limit is reached SIGXCPU is sent
                case SIGKILL: // when hard limit is reached SIGKILL is sent
                    printf ("Time Limit Exceeded\n");
                    break;
                default: // I didn't handle all the signals, so I made everything else a run time error
                    printf ("Run Time Error\n");
                    break;
            }
        }

        ptrace (PTRACE_KILL, pid, NULL, NULL); // Kill the process If it is not killed

        gettimeofday (&end, NULL); // This is working fine
        double time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + 1e-6 * (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
        printf ("%lf\n", time);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use ptrace, you can send signals to the child with `kill(2)` and get the exit status via `wait(2)`, if it exited because of a signal use WTERMSIG.

The problem is probably that you're using system(), so the grader actually runs in a *third* process, not in the child.

N.B personally I wouldn't use system() with file redirections like that, I'd set up pipes then use exec() in the child, so the grader actually runs in the child.  Or I'd just use my [pstreams](http://pstreams.sf.net) library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..
Ok, I removed ptrace.. But that doesn't change enything.. This code I have here only kills the process when it exceeds a certain limit, but it doesn't tell me which. That is the biggest problem :(

Comment: See my edited answer, the child doesn't get the signal, the _grand_ child process does, the one started by the system() call. The child just waits for that to finish.

Comment: ... And exits cleanly. You could try making the child use the return value of system() as its exit status.